# Points plotted backward when specifying xticks

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I ran into a weird issue when plotting a time-series.
In the first plot, everything works fine.
In the second plot, however, the points before the first xtick seem to be plotted backwards.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: Example plot]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in = x,
    xticklabel style = {rotate = 30, anchor = north east},
]
\addplot+ table [
    col sep = comma,
    x = datetime,
    y = temperature,
] {temperature.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in = x,
    xticklabel style = {rotate = 30, anchor = north east},
    xtick = {
        2019-09-17,
        2019-09-18,
        2019-09-19
    },
]
\addplot+ table [
    col sep = comma,
    x = datetime,
    y = temperature,
] {temperature.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

```
datetime,temperature
2019-09-16 15:00:00,23.16315384615385
2019-09-16 16:00:00,23.143547169811324
2019-09-16 17:00:00,22.819166666666657
2019-09-16 18:00:00,22.665943396226414
2019-09-16 19:00:00,22.524074074074065
2019-09-16 20:00:00,22.327351851851844
2019-09-16 21:00:00,22.055399999999988
2019-09-16 22:00:00,21.858518518518512
2019-09-16 23:00:00,21.68958181818182
2019-09-17 00:00:00,21.56796296296297
2019-09-17 01:00:00,21.460444444444445
2019-09-17 02:00:00,21.351629629629624
2019-09-17 03:00:00,21.25550909090908
2019-09-17 04:00:00,21.159444444444446
2019-09-17 05:00:00,21.1452909090909
2019-09-17 06:00:00,21.89207407407407
2019-09-17 07:00:00,22.93842592592592
2019-09-17 08:00:00,22.316981481481484
2019-09-17 09:00:00,23.08466037735848
2019-09-17 10:00:00,23.504370370370367
2019-09-17 11:00:00,23.426584905660366
2019-09-17 12:00:00,23.305454545454545
2019-09-17 13:00:00,23.08659259259259
2019-09-17 14:00:00,22.753166666666658
2019-09-17 15:00:00,22.512218181818174
2019-09-17 16:00:00,22.557566037735846
2019-09-17 17:00:00,22.3393396226415
2019-09-17 18:00:00,21.815672727272723
2019-09-17 19:00:00,21.519555555555556
2019-09-17 20:00:00,21.40996363636363
2019-09-17 21:00:00,21.143277777777776
2019-09-17 22:00:00,20.917226415094337
2019-09-17 23:00:00,20.730055555555552
```

Comment: as much as I can tell you did not have the data for 2019-09-19, so that could be a reason for such change in display of your time-series. If you change: `xtick = {
     2019-09-16,
     2019-09-17,
     2019-09-18
    },`, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `date ZERO`, as is written in section 4.21 of the pgfplots manual.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{temperature.dat}
datetime,temperature
2019-09-16 15:00:00,23.16315384615385
2019-09-16 16:00:00,23.143547169811324
2019-09-16 17:00:00,22.819166666666657
2019-09-16 18:00:00,22.665943396226414
2019-09-16 19:00:00,22.524074074074065
2019-09-16 20:00:00,22.327351851851844
2019-09-16 21:00:00,22.055399999999988
2019-09-16 22:00:00,21.858518518518512
2019-09-16 23:00:00,21.68958181818182
2019-09-17 00:00:00,21.56796296296297
2019-09-17 01:00:00,21.460444444444445
2019-09-17 02:00:00,21.351629629629624
2019-09-17 03:00:00,21.25550909090908
2019-09-17 04:00:00,21.159444444444446
2019-09-17 05:00:00,21.1452909090909
2019-09-17 06:00:00,21.89207407407407
2019-09-17 07:00:00,22.93842592592592
2019-09-17 08:00:00,22.316981481481484
2019-09-17 09:00:00,23.08466037735848
2019-09-17 10:00:00,23.504370370370367
2019-09-17 11:00:00,23.426584905660366
2019-09-17 12:00:00,23.305454545454545
2019-09-17 13:00:00,23.08659259259259
2019-09-17 14:00:00,22.753166666666658
2019-09-17 15:00:00,22.512218181818174
2019-09-17 16:00:00,22.557566037735846
2019-09-17 17:00:00,22.3393396226415
2019-09-17 18:00:00,21.815672727272723
2019-09-17 19:00:00,21.519555555555556
2019-09-17 20:00:00,21.40996363636363
2019-09-17 21:00:00,21.143277777777776
2019-09-17 22:00:00,20.917226415094337
2019-09-17 23:00:00,20.730055555555552
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in = x,
    xticklabel style = {rotate = 30, anchor = north east},
]
\addplot+ table [
    col sep = comma,
    x = datetime,
    y = temperature,
] {temperature.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in = x,
    xticklabel style = {rotate = 30, anchor = north east},
    xtick = {
        2019-09-17,
        2019-09-18,
        2019-09-19
    },date ZERO=2019-09-16
]
\addplot+ table [
    col sep = comma,
    x = datetime,
    y = temperature,
] {temperature.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why not just use: `xtick = { 2019-09-16, 2019-09-17, 2019-09-18 }` without `date ZERO`?

Comment: @Raaja Thanks! The reason is that, according to my interpretation, the OP only wants two ticks. (Another reason is that I want to express that this is not a bug.)

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification

Comment: When not set explicitly shouldn't `date ZERO` be set automatically to the first point? Why does that not work?

Comment: @Claudio It does work. The first point is `2019-09-16 15:00:00`, and not `2019-09-16`.

Comment: That is exactly my question. If I set it explicitly to `2019-09-16 15:00:00`, it works. If I do not (which should then pick up that same value), it does not work.

Comment: @Claudio Notice that, if you set `date ZERO` to `2019-09-16 15:00:00`, the `15:00:00` will be gobbled. Which is why this works. Try setting `date ZERO=2019-09-17` to see what I mean. If you want to say that it should not be necessary to add `date ZERO`, then I agree.

Comment: I am still not entirely satisfied with this. The documentations says "the first encountered coordinate is used", so I would expect the default value to be `2019-09-16 15:00:00`, which would be gobbled to `2019-09-16`, which would produce the correct output. Instead it seems to be take the value `2019-09-17`. Unless "the first encountered coordinate is used" refers also to ticks, but I would expect it to refer only to the data themselves.

Comment: @Claudio You may add a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/) or whatever you like to do. All I can do on this site is to provide you with a simple solution that works. If you want to the pgfplots internal to be rewritten, this site is not the appropriate forum.

Comment: By "not entirely satisfied with this" I meant your explanation, not PGFPlots implementation. According to the documentation, day `16` should have been picked as default zero value, but instead day `17` was picked. You explicitly "express[ed] that this is not a bug", so I don't understand why this happens. Anyway, this solves my specific problem so I will leave it at that.

Comment: @Claudio Well, that’s up to you. I have run several times into users who, when they encounter a behavior that is different from what they hoped it would be, immediately want to see a bug. I am more on the side of the package authors, who spend a lot of time and efforts in providing us with packages as great as pgfplots. If you feel that you want to improve the packages, there are dedicated sites for that, but not this one.